# Find routers in bridge mode on network

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have 3 routers on my network.

Only one does the actual routing, the other 2 act as "switches" and wireless access points. This was accomplished by disabling DHCP and changing the IP ranges, so none of the routers have conflicting address ranges.

A fairly lengthy cable in the network has gone bad and has limited my connection speed to 10Mb/s half duplex. Until I replace the cable, I want to disable auto negotiation and attempt to use 100Mb/s or 1000Mb/s link speeds. The "switch" (router) in question is in a *difficult* location to reach.

How would I figure out the IP addresses of these other two routers? I don't recall exactly what they were set to, but they are on class C networks.

I am running Fedora, so Linux commands would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This was an easy fix. Install `arp-scan` and scan every network range from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.0

Single line bash for loop:

```
for i in {0..255}; do sudo arp-scan --interface=enp0s25 192.168.$i.0/24 | grep 192; done
```

Make sure to replace `enp0s25` with you own network interface.

You can find your network interface using `ip addr`. For example:

```
> $ ip addr                                                                 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:75:98:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.15/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp0s25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```